# Switching from Array to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures

I have some code that I want to convert over to using an an arraylist.

How would I go about generating numbers randomly in the array

When i used an array i did:

```java
public void generateNumbers() {

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++ ) {
            numbersArray[i] = rand.nextInt((50 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        }   

    } //generateNumbers()
```

Is there an equivalent of array[i] in ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not immediately clear what your question is, so I will address the the direct question you asked in the end:

> Is there an equivalent of array[i] in ArrayList?

It depends on what you're doing with it. You would use `nameOfArrayList.set(i, *value*)` to set the value, and `nameOfArrayList.get(i)` to retrieve the value. There are a lot more methods in the `ArrayList` class. I strongly suggest that you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

You also need to note that `ArrayList`s do not work like arrays. The former are mutable while the latter are not. You can read up on it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stream API to generate array or list of random values:

```java
public static List<Integer> getRandomList(int size, int maxValue) {

    Random random = new Random();
    return IntStream.range(0, size)
                    .map(x -> 1 + random.nextInt(maxValue))
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Similarly, an array can be generated:

```java
public static int[] getRandomArray(int size, int maxValue) {

    Random random = new Random();
    return IntStream.range(0, size)
                    .map(x -> 1 + random.nextInt(maxValue))
                    .toArray();
}
```

Comment: In a "productive" system I probably would prefer this solution, with the only adjustment that I return a IntStream instead of a List or int[], but for a beginner this may be a bit overwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int listSize = 5;
    List<Integer> numbersList = new ArrayList<>(5)
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++ ) {
        numbersList.add(rand.nextInt());
    }
```

Arrays and Lists work differently. Arrays have a static size while lists increase their size with each item added.